# How to cancel ValueTask<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation

I know how to cancel a Task, but couldn't find any information on how to add cancellation to ValueTask methods.
Normally I would cancel a Task like this:

```
public async Task<int> Foo(
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcsCancel =
        new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

    cancellationToken.Register(() =>
    {
        tcsCancel.TrySetCanceled();
    });

    Task<int> task = LongOperation();

    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(
        tcsCancel.Task,
        task).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return await completedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Or like this:

```
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    return Task.FromCanceled<int>(cancellationToken);
```

The things is, that ValueTask has neither FromCanceled nor WhenAny. Should I just do ...

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the cancellation token into `LongOperation();`? What you're doing seems strange and I'm not convinced that it will cancel `LongOperation();` so much as ignore its result.

Comment: never mind the logic. I just realized some mistakes I made. But I'd still like to know in general how you add cancellation support with ValueTask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kind of "cancellation" you're referring to isn't a real cancellation; you're cancelling the *wait*, not the *operation*.

You can do the same kind of fake-cancellation with `ValueTask<T>`; you just need to convert it to `Task<T>` in order to do it:

```
public async ValueTask<int> Foo(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  using var tcsCancel = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  using var registration = cancellationToken.Register(() =>
  {
    tcsCancel.TrySetCanceled();
  });

  ValueTask<int> valueTask = LongOperation();
  Task<int> task = valueTask.AsTask();
  var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(
      tcsCancel.Task,
      task).ConfigureAwait(false);

  return await completedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! The reason why I need to fake cancellation is because the SocketTaskExtensions.ReceiveAsync doesn't support cancellation. But I just realized that they added an overload with ValueTask which takes a CancellationToken. Do you know by any chance if this CancallationToken cancels the ReceiveAsync properly? Or is is also just a fake cancellation? I couldn't find any reference or source code to this method to verify.

Comment: There is no way to really cancel an IO operation, unless somehow this is supported by the driver.  Cancelling an IO operations means just ignoring the result of it.

Comment: @Josh: Socket receives aren't cancelable. Think about it this way: if your code did cancel a receive, then it cannot know what state that socket is in. This is true regardless of API/runtime/language/OS. The only proper way to cancel any socket operation is to close the socket, which cancels *all* socket operations.